# what is .convert() function in loading images within python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have a bit a code which goes like this

```
infobackground = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir,"infobackground.jpg")).convert()
```

What does the `.convert()` part of the line do? It seems to make no difference with or without it.

Comment: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`convert()` converts the image into the format used by the display. That means it will be faster to `blit()` on the screen. If the formats don't match blit() has to convert every time, and that is an expensive operation that you want to do only once. The code will work without it but it will be slower if you blit the image multiple times.